# Using arrays for tetris pieces and grid. Why won't this piece show up completely?

Tags: javascript, matrix, tetris

Here's the code, below is a link to the jsfiddle.

The first row of the block isn't drawn for some reason, all these 2 dimension for loops are hard for me to wrap my head around, and can't find the reason why the block is only being drawn from the second row and not complete.

The add_block function is supposed to read array data from any block and put it on the grid where my x and y coordinates are.

If there's anyone who knows how to rotate the block, that would be cool too, i know in order to turn something +90 degrees i need to transpose and then revese each row, but it hasn't really worked in earlier tries.

I know i'm not good at explaining but i'll be sure to answer any of your questions.
Thanks in advance! I really want to have a complete picture of how arrays and double for loops interact with eachother, in my head.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 500;

var grid_columns = 10;
var grid_rows = 15;
var grid_cell_size = 10;

var grid = [];
function create_empty_grid(){
    for(var i=0;i<grid_columns;i++){
        grid[i] = [];
        for(var j=0;j<grid_rows;j++){
            grid[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    // END DOUBLE FOR LOOPS
}
function clear_grid(){
    for(var i=0;i<grid_columns;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<grid_rows;j++){
            grid[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    // END DOUBLE FOR LOOPS
}

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var w = 2;
var h = 3;

var block = [];
block[0] = [
    [1,0,0,0],
    [1,1,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0]
];
function add_block(num){
    var b = block[num];
    for(var i=0;i<w;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<h;j++){

            if(i >= x && j >= y && i <= w && j <= h){
                grid[i][j] = b[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    // END DOUBLE FOR LOOPS
}

function draw(){
    for(var i=0;i<grid_columns;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<grid_rows;j++){
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            if(grid[i][j] === 1){
                ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            }else if(grid[i][j] === 0){
                ctx.fillStyle = "green";
            }
            ctx.fillRect(i*grid_cell_size,j*grid_cell_size,grid_cell_size-1,grid_cell_size-1);
        }
    }
    // END DOUBLE FOR LOOP
}
function update(){

}
function tick(){
    clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    clear_grid();
    draw();
    update();
}

create_empty_grid();
add_block(0);
draw();
```

[View in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NeuroTypicalCure/w2epqfL6/)

Comment: In `b[i][j]`, please note that `i` refers to the y-axis of your matrix and `j` to the x-axis. You're doing it the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using `i` and `j` to represent "block" coordinates, and
`x` and `y` to represent "grid" coordinates. So I think this condition is wrong:

```
if(i >= x && j >= y && i <= w && j <= h){
                grid[i][j] = b[i][j];
            }
```

I think all you really need here is to replace the `if` statement with something like:

```
 grid[i+x][j+y] = b[i][j];
```

But as @Arnauld pointed out, there is also a bit of confusion about whether i,j denotes "row, column" or "column, row", and it looks like your usage is opposite from the way the arrays are initialized. In other words, you're using:

`grid[row][column]` and `b[row][column]`

but the way you laid out the arrays, it needs to be

`grid[column][row]` and `b[column][row]`

So you'll need to make a few adjustments here and there to make the code do what you want.

Comment: Changed every "i" to a "j" and "j" to an "i", honestly this doesn't make sense because x comes before y in the alphabet like "i" comes before "j".    

I did as you said, but changing the if statement didn't change anything.


Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/NeuroTypicalCure/w2epqfL6/1/

Comment: @only: Part of becoming a skilled software developer is knowing when to abandon your intuition and "common sense" about how things are "supposed" to work, and understanding exactly how to accurately express your intentions in the language you're working with.

Comment: How is your philosophical comment supposed to help me? I wouldn't be here if i knew how to accurately express my intentions. I just want to learn, if you roughly tell me where to look or how i go about fixing this i'm going to take it with me in other projects, i can't figure everything out myself like some coding genius, i'm just normal.

Answer (score 0):

The "b" arrays were upside-down for some reason so i changed `grid[j+x][i+y] = b[j][i]` to `grid[j+x][i+y] = b[i][j]` this displays the full block, but i still can't visualise the arrays or be able to prevent these problems in the future.
Arrays are so confusing to me.

I'll figure it out eventually i guess, but a day has to go by.

Comment: "For some reason" -> "Because that's how I wrote it".

Comment: I didn't know these would end up that way, don't make me feel even more stupid than i already am please